# Declare a value as object?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, casting

In C# we do

```
byte[] imageData = new byte[];
SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ImageData", (object)imageData));
```

which makes the imageData variable as an object.

But How do i do this in Visual Basic??

```
Dim imageData As byte() = new Byte()
SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ImageData", ?? ) <-----What Should i do here?
```

Thanks

Just a bit of update of this question

My code is like this

```
conn.Open() 
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT PhotoID From Photo " & str8 & " And Photo = @Photo", conn) 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", CType(Photo, Object)) 
Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter() 
adapter.SelectCommand = cmd 
adapter.Fill(table) <------when approach this line 
PhotoID = table.Rows(0)("PhotoID")
```

It comes out error like this: 
The data types image and varbinary are incompatible in the equal to operator. What should I do?? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want some thing like this.

```
Dim imageData As Byte() =  New Byte() 
SqlCom.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ImageData",CType(imageData, Object)))
```